# Solving conditional probability problems

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm trying to solve the following problem

[image: The question]

I have tried setting up two events, A = the event in which the letter is originally a b. And B = the event in which the letter a is reproduced. Thus P(A $\cap$ B) will give me the desired probability for question a) if I'm thinking correctly but apparently that is not the right approach so now I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Let $X$ be the true letter and $Y$ the copied letter. You know all the probabilities of the form $P(X=x)$ and $P(Y=y|X=x)$ and need to find one of the form $P(Y=y|X=x)$. Use Bayes' rule.